# python error while inserting node in binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

I am trying to write a binary tree implementation in python, but am getting an error while adding a child node using recursion. I rarely use python and could not understand where addChild() is given 4 args. As per my understanding, I have given only 3 same as the function prototype. Please ignore other functions implementation.

Here's my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z.py", line 50, in <module>
    obj.addChild(12, "hari")
  File "z.py", line 42, in addChild
    self.addChild(current.get_rightChild(), key, value)
TypeError: addChild() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key = None, value = None, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.leftchild = leftChild
        self.rightChild = rightChild
        self.parent = parent

    def get_key(self):
        return self.key

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def get_leftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild    

    def get_rightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def get_parent(self):
        pass

    def isLeaf(self):
        pass

    def isRoot(self):
        pass

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, key = None, value = None, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None):
        self.root = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)

    def addChild(self, key, value):
        if self.root is None:
           self.root = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)
        else:
           current = self.root
           if current is None:
               current = Node(key = None, value = None, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)
           elif current.get_key() < key:
                   self.addChild(current.get_rightChild(), key, value)
           elif current.get_key() > key:                
                   self.addChild(current.get_leftChild(), key, value) 




obj = BinaryTree(10, "ram")
obj.addChild(12, "hari")
```

Comment: Small hint to simplify your code: tree is a recursive structure -- children of the root can also be treated like trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addChild` method takes 3 arguments ( including `self`) but you're passing it 4 arguments(including `self`).

Change :

```
def addChild(self, key, value):
```

to :

```
def addChild(self, rightChild, key, value):
```

i.e, add one more parameter before key.

**UPDATE**

You're getting the error cuz of this :

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, key = None, value = None, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None):
        self.root = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)

    def addChild(self, key, value):
        if self.root is None:
           self.root = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)
        else:
           current = self.root
           if current is None:
               current = Node(key = None, value = None, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)
           elif current.get_key() < key:
```

> self.addChild(current.get_rightChild(), key, value) #error here given 4 params

```
           elif current.get_key() > key:
```

> self.addChild(current.get_leftChild(), key, value) #error here given 4 params

**UPDATE 2**

replace your `addChild` method with this :

```
def addChild(self, key, value):
    if self.root is None :
        self.root = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)
    else:
        self._addChild(self.root, key, value)

def _addChild(self, node, key, value):
    if(value < node.get_key()):
        if(node.leftChild != None):
            self._addChild(value, node.leftChild)
        else:
            node.leftChild = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = node)
    else:
        if(node.rightChild != None):
            self._addChild(value, node.rightChild)
        else:
            node.rightChild = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = node)
```

Comment: sorry could not get i have given only tree args in self.addChild(current.get_leftChild(), key, value)
     
arg1 -  current.get_leftChild()        
arg2 - key     
arg3 - value

Comment: first argument of every class method in python is a reference to the current instance of the class.

Comment: so when you're calling `self.addChild(current.get_leftChild(), key, value)` it's like this : `addChild(self, current.get_leftChild(), key, value)`

Comment: so `self.addChild(current.get_leftChild(), key, value)` has 4 args : `arg1 = self` `arg2 =  current.get_leftChild()` `arg3 = key` `arg4 = value`

Comment: while adding the additonal args in the function addChild()
prototype will get changed and i will not be able to call 
addChild() with only two argument key 12 and value "hari"
it gives following error at line obj.addChild(12, "hari")
i want to avoid this situation?


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z.py", line 50, in <module>
    obj.addChild(12, "hari")
TypeError: addChild() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)